# How would I subdivide an arbitrary cube into smaller cubes?

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, 3d, geometry

I'm trying to write an algorithm that will split an arbitrary quad into smaller quads that all have the same x, y, and z scales (so, cubes). Right now I have code that splits quads into scaled down versions of themselves, but I'd like the ratio to be 1:1:1. How would I modify the code below to do that?

```
for (int x=0; x < 2; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < 2; y++) {
        for (int z=0; z < 2; z++) {
            GameObject newCube = Instantiate(gameObject);
            newCube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                newCube.transform.localScale.x/2,
                newCube.transform.localScale.y/2,
                newCube.transform.localScale.z/2
            );
            newCube.transform.position = new Vector3(
            newCube.transform.position.x + ((x-0.5f) * newCube.transform.localScale.x),
            newCube.transform.position.y + ((y-0.5f) * newCube.transform.localScale.y),
            newCube.transform.position.z + ((z-0.5f) * newCube.transform.localScale.z)
        );
    }
}
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Comment: clarify .. arbitrary QUAD is (should be) planar object with 4 vertexes. Scaled down QUAD is not square nor cube. If you really want cubes instead then you are talking about meshes and not QUADs anymore. So which is it (what exactly is the input show example)? Also how many squares/cubes/QUADS you want in subdivision (based on area/volume/size, constant like 4, other )?  Answer is really different for each combination of this. Had changed title so it more match your code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to make squares from a rectangle (actually the 3D equivalent of those, but whatever).

So your inner squares must have a side, at most, half of the SMALLER side of the rectangle. And, since they are squares, all the sides must have the same size. So, you must find which is the smaller side of x, y and z, and create your cubes with all sides set to half of that value.

Putting that into your code:

```
for (int x=0; x < 2; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y < 2; y++) {
        for (int z=0; z < 2; z++) {
            GameObject newCube = Instantiate(gameObject);
            var cubeSize = Math.Min(oldQuad.x, Math.Min(oldQuad.y, oldQuad.z)) / 2;
            newCube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                cubeSize,
                cubeSize,
                cubeSize
            );
            newCube.transform.position = new Vector3(
            newCube.transform.position.x + ((x-0.5f) * newCube.transform.localScale.x),
            newCube.transform.position.y + ((y-0.5f) * newCube.transform.localScale.y),
            newCube.transform.position.z + ((z-0.5f) * newCube.transform.localScale.z)
        );
    }
}
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Since you told nothing about how you want to position them, I keep that part the same.